# Stop loop executed by an event in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, algorithm, dom, search

I have a long list of data and want to get all types of similar data. When my user type on an input field it will show similar data. when another value is typed or input change, the previous execution must stop.
But it runs the whole function in every value change.

(**note**: I don't want only one matched value but also all types of matched value. Also, my data list is an HTMLCollection, and I used for-of loop.)

[image: browser console on input change in browser]

```js
function search(target) {
  console.log('before loop')
  for (let i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
    console.log('search all similar ', target.value)
  }
  console.log('after loop')
}
```

```html
<input type="text" oninput="search(this)" placeholder="search...">
```

to stop.

Comment: The way JS works in the browser, you *cannot* have two loops executed simultaneously.  One will need to completely finish for the next input event to be processed since the entire UI thread is blocked..

Comment: how can I stop running the loop? based on input?

Comment: I think it's good for you to `debounce` the `search` so that your expensive operation inside search runs only after the `burst` interval of `debounced` function is completed.

Comment: What you might be able to do is [debounce your search input](https://css-tricks.com/debouncing-throttling-explained-examples/) so it only activates say, 500 ms after the last input from the user. Lots of search fields do this. You can play around with the debounce timeout but 400-600 is around normal. Allows the user to type in a few things and stop.

Comment: I know debounce is a solution. But I want to stop long-time execution, suppose for 5000 data users search is already running and another input inserted.

Comment: can you add a `break` statement in your loop? take a look at [Break and Continue](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_break.asp)

Comment: I tried with `break`. but it's not working in my criteria. Can you please try this snippet @wittgenstein

Comment: Well, you cannot do it with this loop. You can only change it so you do the work in batches and then `setTimeout`/`setInterval` the next batch of work, so you allow UI thread updates. Then when the next batch starts, you check if there is new input and if so, abort. But this is quite finicky. Also, would slow down the searching. You're better off making the search in the backend in that case, so it can handle cancellations and overrides more cleanly.

Comment: I have no intention to search in the backend, is it possible to keep this loop inside setTimeout and once its starts iterating over long data and if the user gives another input it will stop previous execution and start a new iteration.